# Node error: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960

Tags: node.js

After updating to BigSur OS started to get the following error when trying to start the application.

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module '/Users/anton/Documents/WebDev/_corporate/app.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

Cannot figure out how to resolve this issue.